# Batch that moves PDFs containing certain numbers into folder that contains the same number

Tags: batch-file

I would like to move certain PDFs into folders corresponding with their file numbers.

For example,
**PDF File Name**: 403property.pdf

Moves to **Folder name:** 403

I'm dealing with lots of PDFs and I would like to move them in their own folders so they can be organized.

I would like the batch to be placed within a folder and once the batch is in the folder it will move the PDF's into their corresponding folder.

I would really appreciate the help thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, PDF is made up in such a way that only humans can read it, so I heavily doubt that batchfile technology is capable of finding a word in a PDF file.

Comment: ... and how should your computer know that he needs to move "403property.pdf" to "403", and not to "40", "4" or even "403pro"? And is it only "xxxproperty.pdf" or is there also "xxxattribute.pdf", "xxxsomethingelse.pdf"?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] a good question. Then please provide a [mcve] of the code you are using and real world examples of the input files. Obfuscating input examples can lead to code that will not provide the expected output.

Comment: where is the numerical part? has fixed size?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a batch code for this file moving task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "ErrorDetected="
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%~dp0*.pdf" /A-D /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "^[0123456789]"') do call :ProcessFile "%%~dp0%%I"
if defined ErrorDetected pause
exit /b

:ProcessFile
set "FileName=%~n1"
set "Number="

:GetFileNumber
set "Number=%Number%%FileName:~0,1%"
set "FileName=%FileName:~1%"
for /F "tokens=* delims=0123456789" %%J in ("%FileName%") do if not "%FileName%" == "%%J" goto GetFileNumber

:CreateFolder
md "%~dp1%Number%" 2>nul
if not exist "%~dp1%Number%\" (
    echo ERROR: Failed to create directory: "%~dp1%Number%"
    set "ErrorDetected=1"
    goto :EOF
)
move /Y %1 "%~dp1%Number%\" >nul 2>nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo ERROR: Failed to move file: %1
    set "ErrorDetected=1"
)
goto :EOF
```

Command **FOR** with the used options first starts one more command process in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line within `'` appended as additional arguments.

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `nul`, `2>nul` and `|`. The redirection operators `>` and `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal characters when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` and `finstr` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

The second `cmd.exe` instance runs the internal command **DIR** to output all files (not directories) matching the wildcard pattern `*.pdf` found in the directory of the batch file. The list of file names output by **DIR** is piped to **FINDSTR** which searches for lines starting with a digit and outputs only the file names beginning with at least one digit.

The output of **FINDSTR** is captured by FOR and processed line by line after started `cmd.exe` terminated itself after finishing executing the command line.

A file name can contain one or more spaces. For that reason it is necessary to use `delims=` to define an empty list of string delimiters to get the complete file name with extension, but without path, assigned to the specified loop variable `I`. The file name is passed with the full path to the called subroutine `ProcessFile`.

The Windows command processor `cmd.exe` is designed for running commands and executables and not for string operations. So the decision to use from all script interpreters installed by default on Windows the oldest one with no support for simple string operations was not a good decision. However, it is possible to get the number at beginning of each PDF file name with a digit as first character and having file extension `.pdf` (in long or short file name) as it can be seen on looking on the three lines below label `GetFileNumber`. The **FOR /F** options `tokens=* delims=0123456789` cause a removal of all digits at beginning of the file name string and assigning the rest of the file name to the specified loop variable `J`.

The subdirectory according to the number is created next with suppressing the error message output by command **MD** if this fails like on directory already existing or for other reasons.

Next is checked if the subdirectory with the determined number from file name exists in directory of the batch and if that is not the case an error message is output to inform the user of the batch file about this error.

Otherwise the file is moved into the subdirectory according to the number at beginning of its file name. That can fail also due to various reasons in which case an error message informs the user about this error.

**NOTE:** The command **MOVE** prompts the user despite using option `/Y` if an existing file in target directory should be overwritten or not if the existing file has the read-only attribute set. The prompt is not visible because of `>nul`. So if you ever detect that the batch file seems to hang, press <kbd>N</kbd> to choose not overwriting the existing read-only file.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains also `%~dp0` (drive and path of argument 0 ... batch file path) and `%~1` (argument 1 without the surrounding `"`) and all other argument references
- `cmd /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `exit /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `move /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`